# Maximum matching in a graph

Tags: c++, graph, matrix

I have an interesting problem:
My program must to find the maximum number of `1`.
But that's not all!. 
If the program has "seen" `1`, then it should clear the entire column and row in which the `1` is located.

The problem I have:
I can not find the maximum number of `1`, I do not know how to do that.

For you I made a small example, I hope it will be clear to you. The program must work like this:

There is a matrix:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
```

The program found `1` (position `[0][0]` I've highlighted it in **black**), and cleared the row and column:

[image: Example 2]

After this we find the next `1`, cleared the row and columnand so on:

[image: Example 3]

At the end, the program should print the number of **black cells**.

In my example it's `4`

How to do it in `C++` code? Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: Please post some code of what you have already tried.  This community is for helping people with code not writing all the code.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you need to clear the matrix so the number of ones to be maximum, or you just have to iterate trough, and remove stuff as you find stuff, and finally count how many stuff you found? The previous one is a bit harder I think.

Comment: With the "clearing" constraint it is not possible for the number printed to exceed the smaller dimension of the matrix, and it will be *less* than that number only if some row or some column is all zero.  Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to do it like this (see code below):  Use two "for" loops and inside the second use conditional "if" to add the third "for" loop to set to 0.

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(cow[j][i]==1)
        {
            cnt++;
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
                cow[k][i]=cow[j][k]=0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

it's not clear how you search for the 'next' 1 in your matrix and if the matrix can only contain 0 and 1. But if there is a clear definition of what 'next' is, then you just code exactly as you have described it above. A possible code snippet looks like this (not tested, not even compiled):

```
 bool find_next_one(int&x, int&y, matrix const&M)
 {
   // next is in (col,row) order
   for(; x!=M.size(0); ++x)
     for(; y!=M.size(1); ++y)
       if(M(x,y)==1) return 1;
   return 0;
 }
 int count_one(matrix const&M_original)
 {
   matrix M(M_original); // make copy where we can set elements to 0
   int count=0;
   int x=0,y=0;
   while(find_next_one(x,y,M)) {
     ++count;
     for(int i=0; i!=M.size(1); ++i) M(x,i) = 0;
     for(int i=0; i!=M.size(0); ++i) M(i,y) = 0;
   }
   return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Noticed this looks like a matrix singularity type check - especially if 1s and 0s are the only thing to be used.

You can check the determinate of the matrix.  Non zero means it is equal to the number of rows and columns (if the matrix is always square.)  If det(0), then use any technique you want to bring the matrix down to reduced form to see how many 0'd columns you have - or just do the reduction first and walk down the diagonal counting.

Heck sorting the columns by their added value, will put it in diagonal form for you.  That would make it pretty easy also to check for 0 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write all the code for you, but will suggest some things to get you on track. You should understand how to iterate over a two dimensional array (the matrix) and also how to iterate over a single row or column within that matrix.

Given a (hard coded) definition of matrix that looks like this:

```
struct Matrix4x4
{
    int        m[4][4];
};
```

To iterate over all elements you want to write something like this:

```
   Matrix4x4 matrix;

   for (size_t row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
   {
       for (size_t col = 0; col < 4; ++col)
       {
           // do something with 'matrix.m[row][col]'
       }
   }
```

This will iterate over your matrix from top left (0,0) to bottom right (3,3). I am assuming that this is the traversal order you have been told to use.

To process a row you want to write something like this:

```
   void FunctionThatOperatesOnARow(Matrix4x4& matrix, size_t row)
   {
       for (size_t col = 0; col < 4; ++col)
       {
           // do something with 'matrix.m[row][col]'
       }
   }
```

To process a column you want to write something like this:

```
   void FunctionThatOperatesOnAColumn(Matrix4x4& matrix, size_t col)
   {
       for (size_t row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
       {
           // do something with 'matrix.m[row][col]'
       }
   }
```

What you need to do now is modify the first bit of code that iterates over all elements and get it to check for a 1. You then need to call the appropriate functions to clear the current column and row (which you can base on the latter two examples).

For the final result you can simply increment a local counter variable each time you detect a 1.